# create different dataframes from loop given a list of stocks

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, stock

I have the following situation: I download in the folder all the sp500 csv files, then I select randomly only k csv files that will be used for some analysis. Then given the files path I want to create k different df. I have arrived to the following dictionary with names and df but i do not know how to separate. Also do not suggest that web.DataReader has the iteration features incorporated, I know. I want to use the files from the folder (to run the code also in offline mode). Thankss

```
with open("C:\\Users\\pie4e\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Analysis\\get_data\\sp500tickers.pickle","rb") as f:
    tickers_sp500= pickle.load(f)
random_stocks= random.choices(tickers_sp500, k=10)
print(random_stocks)
d={}
for stock in random_stocks:
    d["df_{}".format(stock)] = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\pie4e\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Analysis\\get_data\\sp500_df\\{}.csv".format(stock))
    print('stock {} loaded from the folder'.format(stock))

for df in d.items():
    print(stock)
    print(df)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here exactly? What you did seems fine to me, except for calling stock in your second for loop, without updating it.

Comment: If you can give me a way to save for every stock, from the dictionary, the data into different pd.DataFrame(), therefore one df for each stock

Comment: They already seem to be in pandas dataframes, since pd.read_csv returns a dataframe. Try calling type(d["df_RCL"]). If it returns pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, it means that your dictionary "d" contains a separate dataframe for each stock. Isn't that what you wanted? You can access its elements by d.values()

Comment: yeah, it works. I was trying to get rid of the dictionary and save the files in the loop like: df_stock= d["df_{}".format(stock)], but actually do not know how to figure it out. Clearly in the df_stock the name changes dinamically for every stock. Im adding a photo for this...

Comment: I see. Having dynamical variable names are impossible. Instead, we can use dictionaries, the same way you did. I think that's the closest solution to your purposes and you should have no problem with accessing the stocks by calling d[f"df_{stock}]", or iterating through d.values().

Comment: yeah, I tried the exec func but it did not work, so I guess this is the only way. Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've solved it! Now it is only a question of knowing how to dynamically call the dataframes in a loop to execute a model function!

[image]